# Vector duplicates the value

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, language-design

Firstly be mercyful, i'm a beginner in C++.

I wrote this code for my interpreter: Reading a line from source and splitting line to words. I using a vector object for storing words. Here is the code, Source is file descriptor (ifstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int UIntegerP;
#define V(X, Y, Z) X##Y##Z
#define Version V(0, 0, 1)

#define Free 0x0

int main(int ACount, char *Arguments[]){
    if(ACount < 2){
        cout << "Venus Interpreter - Engine V: " << Version << " - Interprate: -I <Source> \n";
    }else{
        if(Arguments[1][0] == '-' && Arguments[1][1] == 'I'){
            if(ACount < 3){
                cout << "Error: No input files \n";
            }else if(ACount > 3){
                cout << "Error: Too much arguments \n";
            }else{
                ifstream Source(Arguments[2]);
                if(Source.good()){  
#                   define __TEST__ 1

                    string Line; 
                    vector<string> Words; 
                    string Word; 

                    while(getline(Source, Line)){ 
                        for(unsigned long Index = 0; Index <= Line.length(); Index++){
                            if(Line[Index] == ' ' or Line[Index] == '\0'){
                                Words.push_back(Word); //Inject the Word to Words
                                Word.clear();
                            } else {
                                Word += Line[Index];
                            }
                        }

#                       if __TEST__
                           cout << Words[0] << "\n";
#                       endif

                        //Interpration starts here
                        Words.clear();  
                    }
                }else{
                    cout << "Error: File does not exist \n";
                }
                Source.close();
            }
        }else{
            cout << "Error: Unknown operand \n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the file interpreted by program:

```
10 * 20 / 5 * 10
Asparagas
```

And this is the output:

```
10
10
```

Like you can see here, value is duplicated. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you see when debugging it?

Comment: Why are you using `getline()`instead of the `operator>>()` input operator?

Comment: Are you under the impression that [`Words.empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty) will clear your vector? Because it won't - it returns a bool showing whether it is empty or not. I fyou want to clear your vector use [`Words.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)

Comment: I don't  use operator>>() because of some performance issue. I change the empty to clear.

Comment: _@Ibrahim_ Post a [MCVE] please that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but this `Index <= Line.length();` should be `Index < Line.length();`

Comment: Off topic: Write `Line[Index] == '\40'` as `Line[Index] == ' '`. Immediately obvious what you are doing, is immune to different character encodings, and saves you having to write a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is that for the line `10 * 20 / 5 * 10` you insert the words into your vector, and then print out its first element

```
#if __TEST__
    cout << Words[0] << "\n";
#endif
```

You then (I assume) think that you are **clearing** the vector with the following line

```
Words.empty();
```

However, this doesn't clear the vector, it returns a boolean showing whether the vector is empty or not ([documentation on vector.empty()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty))

To clear your vector you should use [`vector.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear)

The second time around your loop, when you're processing `asparagus`, you print the first element in the vector, which is `10`, because it's still in the vector from the first `getline`

Comment: Okay, no problem. I forget the change empty to clear.